# Kubernetes scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

Does the Kubernetes scheduler assign the pods to the nodes one by one in a queue (not in parallel)?

Based on [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduler-perf-tuning/#how-the-scheduler-iterates-over-nodes), I guess that might be the case since it is mentioned that the nodes are iterated round robin.

I want to make sure that the pod scheduling is not being done in parallel.

Comment: yes, it iterates in round robin fashion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Taking into consideration all the processes `kube-scheduler` performs when it's scheduling the pod, the answer is **yes**.

### Scheduler and pods

> For **every newly created pod or other unscheduled pods**, kube-scheduler
> selects an optimal node for them to run on. However, **every container**
> **in pods** has different requirements for resources and every pod also
> has different requirements. Therefore, existing nodes need to be
> filtered according to the specific scheduling requirements.
>
> In a cluster, Nodes that meet the scheduling requirements for a Pod
> are called feasible nodes. If none of the nodes are suitable, the pod
> remains unscheduled until the scheduler is able to place it.
>
> The scheduler finds feasible Nodes for a Pod and then runs a set of
> functions to score the feasible Nodes and picks a Node with the
> highest score among the feasible ones to run the Pod. The scheduler
> then notifies the API server about this decision in a process called
> binding.

[Reference - kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler).

> The scheduler determines which Nodes are valid placements for **each Pod
> in the scheduling queue** according to constraints and available
> resources.

[Reference - kube-scheduler - synopsis](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/#synopsis).

In short words, `kube-scheduler` picks up pods one by one, assess them and its requests, then proceeds to finding appropriate `feasible` nodes to schedule pods on.

### Scheduler and nodes

Mentioned link is related to nodes to give a fair chance to run pods across all `feasible` nodes.

> Nodes in a cluster that meet the scheduling requirements of a Pod are
> called feasible Nodes for the Pod

Information here is related to default `kube-scheduler`, there are solutions which can be used or even it's possible to implement self-written one. Also it's possible to run [multiple schedulers in cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/).

### Useful links:

- [Node selection in kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/#kube-scheduler-implementation)
- [Kubernetes scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler)